# Is that work of a web designer allowed?

Tags: work

Assalamu alaikum, 
I am working as a web designer and developer for 3 years. 
I have intended recently to create general products that can be used in halal or haram and sell them worldwide. 
One of these products is a template for "Our team" pages which has different layouts for the team of any company. The buyer is responsible for putting the images himself and of course in this time, a lot of companies have women in their team and they don't mind having their photos to be published online. 
I want to ask is this halal or haram? 
I don't upload the photos myself. Only the buyer. 
Is this like selling weapons in time of fitnah (temptation) ? 
and if it is not haram, what if someone comes to me to fix some issues on his website not related to the photos themselves and I found his site contains some haram photos of women but the requirements aren't related to the photos  and are related to design conflicts? 
If this work is haram, then the money gained from it is haram also?

Answer (score 1):

You just created a product to sell to the customers. What they will do with it is their responsibility, not yours.

Rest assured with the help of Allah.

Comment: If you sell a knife to someone who is going to kill some people. Will that be halal?

Comment: If you 100 % knew about it then yeah it would be halal. But that person can use it to cut his meat for all we know. People can't know everything about other people otherwise you should make up a profile of everyone you sell goods too.

Comment: @Anonymous I: *haram